# How to get the value of text_field into hidden field of the same form in ROR 4.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Dear ROR Expertise friends, 
This is my controller method:

```
def balance
  @balance = current_customer.transactions.sum(:debit) - current_customer.transactions.sum(:credit)  
end
```

Here customer and transactions both are controller. Transactions model belongs to Customers model.

This is my form using which customer can deposit money in their bank accounts. In this form, I have a hidden_field which is trying to update the balance column of customers' table. To get the latest balance, I have created a method in my transaction controller which is actually returning the latest balance, before the action carried out.

```
  <%= f.hidden_field :balance, value:"#{@balance} + #{:debit}" %>
```

Here,  I want to achieve to update balance column by adding instance of method (@balance) and the value of debit field. Being a newbie on Rails side, I don't know how to get the value of t.text_field into my hidden_field. I googled, nut unfortunately failed to find the exact solution which I am looking for. How can I get this done.Your suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is `:debit` a model attribute coming into the view or is it being set by the user within the view?

Comment: debit attribute is set by user within the view. Its application for Automated tailor machine(ATM)

Comment: You will need Javascript to make a real-time update to the form like that but you should think through the design carefully to make sure that it makes sense.  For instance, if Javascript is disabled or for some reason not available in the browser, the functionality will need to degrade gracefully (and not, for example, allow someone to take more money out than they have in their account).

Comment: Thanks Steve! I have all conditions in my program. I am able to send user out of withrawal window when system found that the entered amount for withdrawal is greater that the balance.